# Angular binding does not work properly

Tags: angular, binding

In a form I have the following control:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)] ="flightChoice.twoWays" id="twoWays" formControlName="TwoWays">
    <option value="false" >one way</option>
    <option value="true">two ways</option>
</select>
```

And then I have the following div:

```
<div *ngIf="flightChoice.twoWays">
    <label for="returnDate">Return Date:</label>
    <br />
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="ReturnDate" type="text" id="returnDate" />
    <br />
</div>
```

When I change the value of the Select control to "two ways" I expect that the div appears. And so correctly does it.
But when I change back to "one way" the div should disappear, but it does not.
Any hint, on how to make this work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
  <div *ngIf="flightChoice.twoWays=== 'true'"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that did it, I thought the === 'true' was implicit

Comment: @user1238784 In this case, it's comparing flightChoice to the string `"true"` as opposed to the boolean value, which is why it's not implicit

Comment: @user1238784 You are **compairing** a string not **boolean** value. Accept if it's helpful

Answer (score 1):

Both strings `'true'` and `'false'` are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (in fact, all non-empty strings are truthy). Because of this, your workflow goes a little like this:

1. `flightChoice.twoWays` starts out holding a falsy value (I don't know what it is in your case - it might be `false`, `undefined`, `null`, etc). This means your `div` is *not* shown, initially.
2. You select "two ways" in the UI, which changes `flightChoice.twoWays` to `'true'` (the string). As this is a truthy value, it results in the `div` being shown on-screen.
3. You select "one way" in the UI, which changes `flightChoice.twoWays` to `'false'` (again, the string). Remember, this is still a truthy value as it's a non-empty string, so your `div` remains on-screen.

You have two options for resolving this - The first has already been pointed out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51113144/2630078), but forces you to work with strings in your supposed type-safe TypeScript code.

If you want to store the boolean values `true` and `false` rather than the strings `'true'` and `'false'`, you can use Angular's `[ngValue]` syntax, which allows you to specify a literal value (e.g. the booleans `true` and `false`) rather than their string representations. Here's what that looks like:

```html
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)] ="flightChoice.twoWays" id="twoWays" formControlName="TwoWays">
    <option [ngValue]="false" >one way</option>
    <option [ngValue]="true">two ways</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, it's as simple as changing the `option`'s `value="true"` to `[ngValue="true"`]. With this change, `flightChoice.twoWays` will be set to a boolean value and allow you to leave your `ngIf` directive unchanged, avoiding the need for working with strings where booleans are more appropriate.